# Mongodb Mongoose - Find documents that match EXACT query

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, find

I need to find document(s) that match my exact query. For example, let my documents be as follows.

```
{"_id":1,"code":1000,"value":"Apple"}
{"_id":2,"code":1001,"value":"Orange"}
```

If I find with code 100, it returns both documents. I need to return "Not Found" instead.

```
db.col.find({code:100});
```

Answer (score 0):

tests this:

```
var query = db.col.find({code:100});
```

// selecting the 'id', 'code' and 'value' fields

```
query.select('_id code value');
```

//execute the query at a later time

```
query.exec(function (err, results) {
   if (err)
         console.log('err:', err);
   console.log(results);
});
```